# Which laptop with processor i7-7700HQ or i7-8550U I should buy?

Tags: laptop, processor, performance

I need to buy Windows laptop for programming. I have some options, One laptop has i7-7700HQ, and other has i7-8550U.

In past, I thought, that U-Series processors are not for workstations and CPU-bound tasks. I wanted to buy some HQ laptop.

Today I have seen some videos and benchmarks, like this:

http://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i7-8550U-vs-Intel-Core-i7-7700HQ/m320742vsm211019

https://www.notebookcheck.net/8550U-vs-7700HQ_9208_8400.247596.0.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxlHioejSEw

Now, I cannot understand, why these processes are almost equals.

Can you give me some advices, which processor should I buy and why?

Comment: In regard to *I cannot understand, why these processes are almost equals*. It is very simple, the i7-8550U is newer and Intel decided to put 4 cores in the new consumer line instead of the dual-core that the U line used to have.

Comment: You did most of the heavy lifting yourself, the i7-8550 U is the better performing processor. In addition, U T S series processors are usually tuned for power savings over performance, so that means that the i7-8550 U is more power efficient.

Comment: The 8th generation processors from Intel have finally been able to cram more cores into a power efficient package, though if you're looking for pure performance, you might want one of the 6 core [H series](https://www.notebookcheck.net/7700HQ-vs-8750H_8400_9576.247596.0.html) CPUs. However, it would be easier for us to provide a good recommendation if you could give us a detailed workload (what compiler? what kind of projects?) and your budget, which would allow us to find a balanced system, perhaps cheaper or faster than you expected. Since laptops usually have soldered on CPUs these days...

Comment: It's usually easier just to group everything in one recommendation request. Be sure to include everything you're likely to want to do.